# i want to try to implement activation hash in Django using python 3.x

Tags: django, python-3.x

```
import random
import base64
import hmac
import hashlib

short_hash = hashlib.sha256(str(random.getrandbits(256)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
username='hp'
activation_key = hashlib.sha256(short_hash + username).encode('utf-8').hexdigest()


short_hash = hashlib.sha256(str(random.getrandbits(256)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[:5]
```

> > > username="hp"
> > >       activation_key = hashlib.sha256(short_hash + username).hexdigest()
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the username name variable before hashing it.

```py
import random
import base64
import hmac
import hashlib

short_hash = hashlib.sha256(str(random.getrandbits(256)).encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
username = 'hp'
concat = short_hash + username
activation_key = hashlib.sha256(concat.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```